# method in deleting a line excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to know the best way to delete a line in excel by using vba

For my project, every specific line is link with a graphic, when i delete the line by using the method

```
Rows(i).delete
```

It appears in my graphic #REF

I've tried the methode

```
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlUp
```

But when I entered data to the same line, it will not used the color which i had attributed to the data on the line

thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By "graphic" I assume you mean Chart. In Excel, if you delete a range on which a series in a chart is based then the series will remain on the chart but display #REF! in the series list. So in addition to deleting the row you will also have to remove the series from the chart. Let's say the name of the chart is "Chart 1":

```
Dim co as ChartObject
Dim c as Chart

Set co = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1")
Set c = co.Chart
On Error Resume next

Do While Err.Number = 0
    c.SeriesCollection("#REF!").Delete
Loop

On Error GoTo 0
```

By placing the above code after your Rows(i).Delete the related series in the chart will also be removed.

Comment: just another question, if i delete the row, how can i create a new row which will link up with the chart like the row which i've deleted above? sorry for the nuissance, i am just a newbies in vba programming

Comment: Why do you want to delete it then? Why don't you just change the values in the row? That way the chart will automatically update with the new values.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use ClearContents?
Something like this:

```
Rows(i).ClearContents
```

This method doesnt clear formats or other things, just the values or formulas.

Comment: by using this method, i am able to clear all the rows, but if i have data on the line below, some of my loop will stop working when they arrive to an empty line and they will forgot about the data bellow.